# Is there a way to pass two elements from different lists in ruby to a function

Tags: ruby, foreach

I am trying to create a Ruby script that take inputs from CSV file with two columns and loop across each elements and pass it to a function.

For example,

CSV file

```
x,y

1,3
4,6
7,9
```

def function(x,y)

So I need to loop across x,y together in the csv file and pass it to the function then get the output of each one.

Is there a simple way to loop across each column in the CSV file and pass both x,y to the function please ?

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please fix the formatting in your "csv file". Is it two rows (with x,y being the header)? or is it a single row? Or is it 4 rows, including a header row? EDIT ok I've edited so it's clearer.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Replace yourfile.csv and myfun appropriately:

```
require 'csv'
  
CSV.foreach('yourfile.csv', headers: true) { |row| myfun(row[0], row[1]) }
```

Comment: I suggest that instead of `myfun(row[0], row[1])` you write `myfun(row['x'], row['y])`, so that the order of the columns does not matter.  It also reads better. If `def myfun(a,b); a.to_i + b.to_i; end`, the expression would print `4`, `10` and `16` on separate lines.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to get the output of the two columns from the CSV file and put them in two different lists ..using this : table = CSV.parse(File.read("test.csv"), headers: true) and then call each column separately table.by_col[0] & table.by_col[1]. Now I have function like this def(id:x,name:y) and I want to loop on both lists and pass each item from each list to id and name.lets say table.by_col[0] have ["1", "2", "3"] and table.by_col[1] have ["chocolate", "bacon", "apple"], first iteration should be id:'1' and name : 'chocolate' and so on.Thank you.